# How to resolve conflicting of pandas.to_datetime with python's built-in datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, date-formatting, python-datetime

Initially I've got

```
print(transactions.Date.loc[0])
>>>30/04/18
```

First I've done

```
transactions['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(transactions['Date'])
```

Now

```
print(transactions.Date.loc[0])
>>>2018-04-30 00:00:00
```

After that I check for an equality condition like so

```
transactions.Date.loc[0] + datetime.timedelta(days=1) == transactions.Date.loc[1]
>>>False
```

So I examine

```
print(transactions.Date.loc[0] + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
>>>2018-05-01 00:00:00 
print(transactions.Date.loc[1])
>>>2018-01-05 00:00:00
```

Turns out both refer to same time, but with a different format. How do I modify my code to get `True` on equality?

***EDIT***: As pointed in the comments, the problem is actually May 1 being transformed to January 5 when I use pd.to_datetime. So the new question is how do I resolve this?

Comment: Try adding date pattern while formatting, ``pd.to_datetime(transactions['Date'], format="")``

Comment: the pattern in `transactions['Date']`  is year/month/day?

Comment: can you print the content of `transactions.Date.loc[0]` without adding the timedelta? just to be sure that the difference is really 1 day

Comment: I've updated the question based on your suggestions. Hope it's more clear. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's a different format and not just January 5 vs May 1?

Comment: pls do `transactions.Date.loc[0] - transactions.Date.loc[1]`

Comment: Oh yess! Before I applied, to_datetime, the format was dd/mm/yy. I think that's why May 1 transformed to January 5!! How do I solve this issue now?

Comment: put `dayfirst=True` inside the `to_datetime` function and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code worked fine, are you sure that the difference between `transactions.Date.loc[0]` and`transactions.Date.loc[1]` is exactly 1 day?

```
>>> l = pd.to_datetime(['2000/23/11', '2000/24/11'], dayfirst=True)
>>> l[0] + datetime.timedelta(days=1) == l[1]
True
>>> print(l[0], l[0] + datetime.timedelta(days=1), l[1], sep='\t')
2000-11-23 00:00:00     2000-11-24 00:00:00     2000-11-24 00:00:00
```

Edit: using your data i've found the error:

with `dayfirst=True` works well

```
>>> l = pd.to_datetime(['30/4/20', '1/5/20'], dayfirst=True)
>>> l[0] - l[1]
Timedelta('-1 days +00:00:00')
```

without it the conversion format is different between the 2 dates

```
>>> l = pd.to_datetime(['30/4/20', '1/5/20'])
>>> l[0] - l[1]
Timedelta('116 days 00:00:00')
```